# When should we extend LiveData class for MVVM architecture in android?

Tags: android, firebase, mvvm, android-livedata

I have a bit of knowledge on LiveData and ViewModel, recently I tried to make an application using firebase real-time DB, but my usual approach of using just LiveData isn't working!.
**I am getting observed when data is changing but it is not bringing any value changes.**
I searched online and stumbled across firebase doc where they wrote a custom LiveData class by extending LiveData my doubt is **when we should go for the approach of extending LiveData?**
and **what is wrong in using just LiveData for this kind of approach?**

Thanks in advance !:)

Answer (score 0):

> when we should go for the approach of extending LiveData?

If you need access to the protected `onActive` and `onInactive` methods to drive your logic.

> what is wrong in using just LiveData for this kind of approach?

I'd have to see your code for that as a minimal verifiable complete example.